# module 'imaplib' has no attribute 'IMAP4_SSl' error in python how to fix in python 3.9

Tags: python, imap

module 'imaplib' has no attribute 'IMAP4_SSl' this is the error I get. PS. I am a beginner.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as `IMAP4_SSl`, but there is `IMAP4_SSL`. You have a lowercase `l` instead of an uppercase `L`. Python is case-sensitive. Notice how in the documentation, the name is all uppercase:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4_SSL